# Desktop VB.NET <> C# converter

Tags: c#, vb.net

I've been using the Developer Fusion's tool for converting code snippets, and now I'm looking for a quality tool to convert entire projects between those languages, with minimum errors. Is there any good one available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting vb.net to c# tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57473/converting-vb-net-to-c-tips)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a some listed on [this page](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/titles/c-to-vb-net-converter.htm).

NOTE:

1. I haven't tried any of them
2. Most appear to be paid for applications.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the best way to do this is use Red Gate .NET Reflector.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Assuming you have the compiled VB.NET assemblies, you can load them in Reflector, and then save the reflected code in C#.